# Use MAPE as a eval metric in XGBoost

Tags: python, metrics, xgboost

I'm trying to use MAPE in my code with XGBoost, however I get this error: "`/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/xgboost_1593723618214/work/src/metric/metric.cc:49: Unknown metric function mape`". I read that the most recent XGBoost upgrade doesn't have this metric working, but on documentation, MAPE is mentioned and I need to use it. Does anyone know how I should implement it? The code that I'm using is present below.

Thank you in advance

```
params = {
# Parameters that we are going to tune.
'max_depth':6,
'min_child_weight': 1,
'eta':.3,
'subsample': 1,
'colsample_bytree': 1,
# Other parameters
'objective':'reg:squarederror', } 

}  
params['eval_metric'] = "mape"
num_boost_round = 999

model = xgb.train(
    params,
    D_train,
    num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
    evals=[(D_test, "Test")],
    early_stopping_rounds=10
)
```

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments.

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)